# configuring xserver for hybrid graphics and HDMI on Ubuntu 20.04 for Razer Stealth 2020 Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, xorg

I've been struggling to configure my system correctly to get my Hybrid Graphics working.

My Laptop has HDMI over usb-c(thunderbolt) and doesn't detect external monitors.
Also I'm unable to boot the system without i915.modeset=0 irrespectively whether I have nouveau, nvidia or no dedicated graphics driver installed.

My system:

```
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D|USB|Intel'
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a12 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 03)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 NHI #0 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
58:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
```

My nvidia driver seems to be correctly installed as I'm able to run programs with gpu acceleration and opengl 4.6:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears -info
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    = 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66
GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation
```

However without using those environment variables it does choose llvmpipe for rendering. This holds true when using prime-select or optirun.

I couldn't to get it to work with neither:

1. bumblebee with and without xorg.conf
2. nvidia propriety driver, prime-select and various xorg.confs including nvidia-xconfig
3. setting nvidia-drv.modeset=1 kernel option fails with "cannot run in framebuffer mode"

In all cases the system locks up and switching to a terminal or restarting the xserver is not possible.

Below is an excerpt of the xorg.log. My logs don't contain any Errors but it suspiciously sets a mode to "NULL" and chooses to render into a virtual screen of size 640 x 480:

```
   14.363] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    14.363] (==) NVIDIA(G0): RGB weight 888
[    14.363] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    14.363] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    14.363] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card0
[    14.363] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[    14.363] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    14.363] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[    14.363] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[    14.364] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[    14.368] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    14.368]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.368]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    14.368] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  450.66  Wed Aug 12 19:41:37 UTC 2020
[    14.368] (II) NVIDIA: The X server supports PRIME Render Offload.
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design (TU117-A) at
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0):     PCI:88:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    14.369] (--) NVIDIA(G0): Memory: 4194304 kBytes
[    14.369] (--) NVIDIA(G0): VideoBIOS: 90.17.50.00.0e
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Validated MetaModes:
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0):     "NULL"
[    14.369] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[    14.369] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[    14.369] (==) NVIDIA(G0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    14.369] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    14.369] (II) Unloading vesa
[    14.370] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    14.370] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    14.370] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    14.370] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    14.370] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    14.394] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Setting mode "NULL"
[    14.398] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    14.398] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Backing store enabled
[    14.398] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[    14.398] (==) NVIDIA(G0): DPMS enabled
[    14.398] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Option "VirtualHeads" is not used
[    14.398] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    14.398] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    14.399] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    14.399] (II) NVIDIA(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    14.399] (II) NVIDIA(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
```

Any advice welcome

EDIT: seems like my system is affected by a critical bug in i915 and is beeing tackled upstream:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/2414

related issues:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063442/after-login-drmdrm-atomic-helper-wait-for-flip-done-drm-kms-helper-error

https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was discovered, adding intremap=off resolves all issues, except the suspend loop.

Source: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/2414#note_631004